HTML element is not found at ngAfterViewInit
I have an Angular component that injects Ace editor. Sometimes in logs (very rare) I can see the following error:
Error: ace.edit can't find div #aceEditor
    at ie.edit (https://stepindev.com/ru/main.fcb9335868d1e005.js:1:1267133)
    at t.ngAfterViewInit (https://stepindev.com/ru/main.fcb9335868d1e005.js:1:467814)


I have never been able to reproduce the issue. And I do not understand what can cause it. My understanding is that at the moment when ngAfterViewInit starts, the DOM is ready and can be used.
So the question is what can be the cause of the problem?
Component's template:
<div id="aceEditor" #editor></div>

<!--Don't recreate console with *ngIf. It must exists all the time to be able to capture all console input/output-->
<sid-console #console class="console" (change)="onIOAppeared()" hidden></sid-console>

<ng-content></ng-content>

ngAfterViewInit handler
    import * as ace from 'ace-builds'

    ...

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.editor = ace.edit('aceEditor');
        this.editor.setTheme('ace/theme/textmate');
        this.editor.session.setMode('ace/mode/python');
        this.editor.setOptions({
            fontSize: '16pt'
        });

        this.editor.on("change", delta => this.change.emit(delta))
        window.addEventListener(this.resizeEvenName, this.resizeEventListener, false);

        // resize after all components above this one are settled. So we can get the correct "top" value
        window.setTimeout(() => this.resizeComponents(), 0);
    }

The container with this component is created dynamically depending on an HTTP request (using *ngIf):
<sid-robot-python-view [task]="$any(task)" *ngIf="isRobotPythonTask()" data-testId="robot-python-view"></sid-robot-python-view>

I would expect the the error never happens. It was logged for Chrome 130.0 and Chrome 109.0 on Windows. I use Angular 14.

According to the Ace editor docs - Edit Function accepts an element instead of a string, could you try this method instead of passing in string.
Here we take a ViewChild of the element, then we pass the nativeElement to the ace editor edit function.
import * as ace from 'ace-builds'
...

...
@ViewChild('aceEditor') aceEditor: ElementRef<any>;
...

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if(this.editor?.nativeElement) {
        this.editor = ace.edit(this.editor.nativeElement);            
        this.editor.setTheme('ace/theme/textmate');
        this.editor.session.setMode('ace/mode/python');
        this.editor.setOptions({
            fontSize: '16pt'
        });

        this.editor.on("change", delta => this.change.emit(delta))
        window.addEventListener(this.resizeEvenName, this.resizeEventListener, false);

        // resize after all components above this one are settled. So we can get the correct "top" value
        window.setTimeout(() => this.resizeComponents(), 0);
    }
}


According to the linked docs, it's either Element or a string. So the replacement shouldn't make any difference.

@ViktarTserashchuk could you try it, maybe the ace editor initialize when the component it self is hidden by ngif

@ViktarTserashchuk ace editor uses document.querySelector to access this element, compared to you passing the element, which is more angular oriented, since we cannot control when the querySelector runs when you pass the input as string

@NarenMurali is correct, partially. Ace actually uses document.getElementById() to get the element only when the argument is a string. If it's an element, your error will never be thrown since that part of the code will never be reached. Moreover it's discouraged to run document.getElementById() in an Angular app since it would try to fetch the element from the entire app DOM instead of just the relevant Angular component. I'd try to send the element as per @NarenMurali's suggestion.

@Barremian, I don't understand why using this.editor?.nativeElement and document.getElementById('aceEditor') can give different results.  getElementById is not deferred. It's called right in the edit() function.  Wouldn't this.editor?.nativeElement be just null as well?

@Barremian, is it like the possibility that  the component with all its internal html elements is created but not attached to the page yet, and because of that getElementById returns null and nativeElement is not null?
